# Pull out a range of data from unique character to unique character using grep or awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep, fasta

I have a moderately large fasta format file that has a complex header. I need to pull a sequence out based on a value (an 8 digit number) from another file. I can get the sequence out using 'grep -20 "value" fasta.file'. Some of the sequences are very large and I often have to adjust the number of lines in order to get the whole sequence. I then have to copy and paste into another file.  Right now, I have too many values (1000) to do this manually.   The tools that I have found to do this haven't worked so far...

The fasta format file looks like this:

```
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818557; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134300789; Stop=134300869; Strand=+; Length=80;
GGATCATTGATGACCATAAAAGATGTGGGAGTCGTCTGAAACATGCATGATGACCACAAC
ATTGAGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818559; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134301675; Stop=134301762; Strand=+; Length=87;
GGATCATTGATGACCAAAAAAAAAAAAACATCTGGGAGTCCTCTGAGACATCCATGATGA
CCACAACATTGGGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
```

If I use the command  `grep -4 "17818557" fasta.fa` I get:

```
ATTGCGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818555; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134299894; Stop=134299978; Strand=+; Length=84;
GGATCATTGATGACCAGAAAAAAATCATCTCGGAGTCCTCTGAGACATCCATGATGACCA
CAACATTGGGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818557; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134300789; Stop=134300869; Strand=+; Length=80;
GGATCATTGATGACCATAAAAGATGTGGGAGTCGTCTGAAACATGCATGATGACCACAAC
ATTGAGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818559; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134301675; Stop=134301762; Strand=+; Length=87;
GGATCATTGATGACCAAAAAAAAAAAAACATCTGGGAGTCCTCTGAGACATCCATGATGA
```

`grep -4` grabs four lines above and below. What I need to do is use the numerical query and pull out just the sequence data below the fasta header (>). It would be nice to collect the sequence below the fasta header to next fasta header, ie from > to >.

I have tried some of the UCSC tools 'faSomeRecord' and some `perl` scripts. They haven't worked with the numerical query in list file or on the command line with and without the 'transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:' addition. I am thinking that it is the colons or because the header includes positions and lengths which are variable.

Any comments or help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 30July14**

Thanks to the help I received here. I was able to get the data from one file to another using this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

filename='21Feb14_list.txt'
filelines=`cat $filename`

for i in $filelines ; do

        awk '/transcript/ && f==1 {f=0;next} /'"$i"'/ {f=1} f==1{print $1}' RaGene-2_0-st-v1.rn4.transcript_cluster.fa

done
```

This pulls out the sequence, but it truncates the data to the wildcard value.  Is there a way to modify this so that I can get the entire header?

example output:

```
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17719499;
ATGCCTGAGCCTTCGAAATCTGCACCAGCTCCTAAGAAGGGCTCTAAGAAAGCTATCTCT
AAAGCTCAGAAAAAGGATGGCAAGAAGCGCAAGCGTAGCCGCAAGGAGAGCTATTCCGTG
TACGTGTACAAGGTGCTGAAGCAAGTGCACCCGGACACCGGCATCTCTTCCAAGGCCATG
GGCATCATGAACTCGTTCGTGAACGACATCTTCGAGCGCATCGCGGGCGAGGCGTCGCGC
CTGGCGCATTACAACAAGCGCTCGACCATCACGTCCCGGGAGATCCAGACCGCCGTGCGC
CTGCTGCTGCCGGGGGAGCTGGCCAAGCACGCGGTGTCGGAAGGCACCAAGGCGGTCACC
AAGTACACCAGCTCCAAGTG
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17623679;
```

Thanks again!!

Comment: Do you mean something like `grep` for "17818557" and then print the header from one ">" to the next ">" that contains "17818557"?

Comment: yes. It would be nice to be able to grab all of the sequence from the header to the beginning of the next header. The header always starts with '>'

Comment: Does Cyrus's answer work for you? Or do you want the header included before that output? Please give an example of the desire output in your original question

Comment: >transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818557; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134300789; Stop=134300869; Strand=+; Length=80;
GGATCATTGATGACCATAAAAGATGTGGGAGTCGTCTGAAACATGCATGATGACCACAAC
ATTGAGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC

Comment: Does `grep -A3 "17818557"` work, or have you already tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/transcript/ {f=0} /17818557/ {f=1} f==1{print}' fasta
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818557; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134300789; Stop=134300869; Strand=+; Length=80;
GGATCATTGATGACCATAAAAGATGTGGGAGTCGTCTGAAACATGCATGATGACCACAAC
ATTGAGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
```

#### How it works:

The code uses a flag, called `f`, to decide if a line should be printed.  Taking each command, one by one:

- `/transcript/ {f=0}`

  If "transcript" appears in the line, indicating a header, we set the flag to `0`.
- `/17818557/ {f=1}`

  If the line contains our key, `17818557`, we set the flag to `1`
- `f==1{print}`

  If the flag is `1`, print the line.

Comment: @skamazin Explanation added.

Comment: @John1024 Thank you so much! I keep seeing great `awk` answers but sometimes they're hard to follow. Real quick, is `f` reserved as a special flag variable by `awk` or could you have used any character?

Comment: @skamazin Any character or name would do. If you want to learn `awk`, you might start with a tutorial such as [this one](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: @John1024 I actually started that one a few days ago! But I suppose I should try to finish it off.

Comment: @John1024 I was able to cobble together a bash script that used the awk code that you posted. However, the entire header doesn't make it into the output. Is there a better way to accomplish this loop with awk?

Comment: @MattThornton I see your script in the updated question.  To get the full line, replace `f==1{print $1}` with `f==1{print}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '1,/17818557/d;/>/,$d' file
```

Output:

```
GGATCATTGATGACCATAAAAGATGTGGGAGTCGTCTGAAACATGCATGATGACCACAAC
ATTGAGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
```

---

**With Header:**

```
id=17818557
sed "/$id/p;1,/$id/d;/>/,\$d" file
```

Output:

```
>transcript_cluster:RaGene-2_0-st-v1:17818557; Assembly=build-Rnor3.4/rn4; Seqname=chr6; Start=134300789; Stop=134300869; Strand=+; Length=80;
GGATCATTGATGACCATAAAAGATGTGGGAGTCGTCTGAAACATGCATGATGACCACAAC
ATTGAGAGTCTGAGGTCCAC
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the header line too? That is kind of important. Thanks again!